# Compile-time detection of accidentally assign a C# property to itself

Tags: c#

Visual Studio C# compiler [warns about accidentally assigning a variable to itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1kzfw0z.aspx), but this warning does not apply to C# properties, only variables. As described in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336847/why-doesnt-the-c-sharp-compiler-stop-properties-from-referring-to-themselves).

However, I would really like something similar that can warn me at compile time if I assign a property to itself.

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2013 but I'm ok if the solution works at least in Visual Studio 2015. Also, I don't use third-party commercial plugins like ReSharper or CodeRush so I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve purchasing something, but I'm open to suggestions.

Do you know how could I accomplish this?

### Background:

I'm very used to the [constructor dependency injection](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) pattern using readonly public ["inspection" properties](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/04/structural-inspection/) to store the received dependency.

For example, assume a class `Foo` that depends on an `ILogger` implementation. The `logger` instance is provided to the class in the constructor, the constructor checks for nulls and stores the dependency in an instance property called `Logger`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; private set; }

    public Foo(ILogger logger)
    {
        if(logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        this.Logger = logger;
    }
}
```

However, I often make the typing mistake of assigning the property to itself instead of the parameter passed to the constructor.

```
public class Foo
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; private set; }

    public Foo(ILogger logger)
    {
        if(logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");
        this.Logger = Logger; // <-- This is wrong. Property assigned to itself.
    }
}
```

Of course I always end up catching these errors while testing and debugging, but it has bitten me several times already and I don't want to keep wasting time in such a silly mistake anymore.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Then try using `private ILogger _logger`, don't think logger must be public

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Was thinking the same, there is probably one already.

Comment: @csharpfolk Thanks, I know that if a use a field I get the warning I mentioned in the first paragraph, but then that wouldn't be relevant to this question about C# properties. Also, check the link about inspection properties, by definition, inspection properties are public. Please don't take this as arrogance or stubbornness: I know I can make those changes, but I'm really curious for a solution to this specific scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the perfect situation for a Live Code Analyzer from VS2015. You could write up a basic analyzer that checks if a property is being assigned to itself and create a error.

Here is a very good tutorial I followed a long time ago to help you get started on how to write one, they are not very hard to do: "[C# and Visual Basic - Use Roslyn to Write a Live Code Analyzer for Your API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx)"

UPDATE: I had some free time so I wrote an analyzer up that does it.

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class SelfAssignmentAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public const string DiagnosticId = "SelfAssignment";

    private static readonly LocalizableString Title = "Do not do self assignment";
    private static readonly LocalizableString MessageFormat = "The variable '{0}' is assigned to itself";
    private static readonly LocalizableString Description = "A variable assignment to itself is likely an indication of a larger error.";
    private const string Category = "Correctness";

    private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics { get { return ImmutableArray.Create(Rule); } }

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKind.SimpleAssignmentExpression);
    }

    private void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var assignmentExpr = (AssignmentExpressionSyntax)context.Node;

        var right = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(assignmentExpr.Right);
        var left = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(assignmentExpr.Left);
        if (!right.Equals(left))
            return;

        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, assignmentExpr.GetLocation(), assignmentExpr.Left.ToString());
        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);

    }
}
```

There may be optimizations you could do that could rule situations out without calling `GetSymbolInfo` (for example checking the text of the left and the right to see that they match) but I leave that as a exercise for you.

EDIT:

The analyzer in action inside Visual Studio 2015:

[image: Analyzer in action]

Comment: I suspected this would be one of the answers and perhaps the 'correct' one.  But I wanted to 'crowdsource' other (hopefully clever) alternatives. If nothing else comes up I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: What about crowd-sourcing making the analyzer itself :)

Comment: Thanks! I don't have a VS2015 instance at the moment, but will try this analyzer as soon as possible.

Comment: Made it work and added screenshot. This is just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you type the parameters, so the error happens less often.

Parameter first:

```
   public Foo(ILogger logger)
   { 
   }
```

Assignment next: **copy/paste the parameter** twice

```
   public Foo(ILogger logger)
   { 
       // this.{paste} = {paste};
       this.logger = logger;
   }
```

Lastly, correct the misspelt property:

```
   public Foo(ILogger logger)
   { 
       this.Logger = logger;
   }
```

Comment: Nice low tech suggestion. I don't know if I will remember to do this, but I like the pragmatism. Thanks.